# Angular JS on keydown get value

Tags: angularjs, textbox

I am new to AngularJS, just making a small filter data table. I have a text box, on `ng-keydown` I am calling a function, in this function I want the value of that textbox.

How can I get it. My code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="ApplicantsListCtrl">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" ng-model="c" ng-keydown="filter()"></p>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

    app.controller('ApplicantsListCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

        $scope.filter = function(){
            console.log($scope.c);
        };
    }]);
```

I am getting undefined in my log.

Is this correct way to do it?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/BmZIYyiYcTnUTiAtGEke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than keydown, use $watch. See the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eH6ZA0cxZ1FZynusP7vo)

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" data-ng-change="key(data)" data-ng-model="data"/>

$scope.key = function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        };
```

This works.

Comment: Glad this helped you

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ng-change="filter(c)"`

Comment: I prefer this option over the watch